# How do I purge/clobber stashed files?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

[Jenkins docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) seem ambiguous about this:

> Stashed files are not otherwise available and are generally discarded
>   at the end of the build.

Soooo "generally" means what? They *should* get discarded by default? Do I need to do something to have them discarded?

Because my stashed files aren't getting discarded. I run this:

```
stash name: "myZip", includes: "${differentEveryTime}.zip"
```

And every time the job runs it keeps adding the new zip file to the "myZip" stash.

I couldn't find anything in the docs about how to control this. I want myZip to clobber everything previously or start empty each job run.

At the start of my pipeline, in my first stage, I do this:

```
step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
checkout scm
```

It seems to successfully cleanup my workspace. Where is the stash actually stored on the filesystem so i can confirm this?

EDIT:
The accepted answer is correct, but for more clarity on my confusion: I wasn't cleaning up the work spaces of my parallel stages, just my main pipeline's workspace. The streams workspaces were persisting and contained the old files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your stash contains files from older runs is most likely because all runs re-use the previous workspace - containing files from previous runs (that you include when creating the ZIP file?

Clean your workspace, e.g. using `git clean -fdx` at the beginning of the job, and your stashes should only include artifacts from the current run. At least it never happened to me that stashes created using the `stash` step accumulated files from previous runs.

Comment: yikes do I really have to do that? I'm already running wscleanup right before checkout: `step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])` right before `checkout scm`

Comment: That should have the same effect, I agree. But I really suggest that you check if those files exist before zipping.

Comment: Actually I don't get why you think it'd `stash`s fault if you provide it the name of a ZIP (which includes old files, correct?).

Comment: Oh wait a sec, I think im being dumb. I'm not running any workspace cleanup in the individual streams- I thought their workspaces got destroyed after a run but i guess not?

Comment: No, workspaces in Jenkins aren't wiped automatically.

Comment: Do you know if there is a setting to just have the streams workspaces totally destroyed after a run?

Comment: What is a "stream"? Such things that execute in parallel using the `parallel`  step? No, you have to explicitly clean up.